# Referencing multiple primary key(s) in another table

Tags: .net, sql, database

I am developing a new web application and for that I also need to define its database structure.

Problem is I have a table called `Department`, containing:

```
id: int
name: varchar
```

And another table called `Employee`

```
id: int
name: varchar
dept: Department.id(s) (Foreign Key)
```

Issue is an employee could belong to multiple departments and I am unable to figure out how to store this information in the table, for e.g.:

If client 001 belongs to Department 004,005 and 006 than how do I store these three department keys in one column i.e. Employee.dept?

I figured out that one possible way could to store them as delimited strings like “004,005,006”, But for this I would have to convert them back and forth to string and int and than search the string for a particular occurrence.

Can anyone kindly help me suggesting an ‘efficient’ and correct solution for this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't store those `ID` as comma separated value. It's a very very bad design. Properly normalize the table.

This is a `Many-to-Many` relationship. So you should have three tables on your schema,

Department

- ID (PK)
- Name

Employee

- ID (PK)
- Name

Employee_Department

- DepartmentID (FK)
- EmployeeID (FK)

---

so when translated to real DDL,

```
CREATE TABLE Department
(
    ID INT,
    NAME VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT dept_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT dept_uq UNIQUE(Name)
)

CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    ID INT,
    NAME VARCHAR(50),
    CONSTRAINT Emp_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT Emp_uq UNIQUE(Name)
)

CREATE TABLE Employee_Department
(
    DepartmentID INT,
    EmployeeID INT,
    CONSTRAINT empdep_pk PRIMARY KEY (DepartmentID, EmployeeID),
    CONSTRAINT empdep_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentID)
        REFERENCES Department(ID),
    CONSTRAINT empdep_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID)
        REFERENCES Employee(ID)
)
```